# How to control static content cache configuration in Tomcat 7 + Struts 1.2

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, struts-1

My static content is **being cached by the browsers and i want to control it**.
But I can't find any related configuration.

The browsers cache the static content only when it accessed through struts action. When I request an image with direct link it is not taken from cache (304).

And oddly, the cached content is received (at first time) without *"expire"* or *"cache-control"* headers. The sole relevant included header is *"Etag"*.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: So is your complaint that the content is being cached through the struts action, or not being cached through the direct url?

Comment: My "complaint" is that i want to control it but can not find the relevant config. I'm suspecting it related to struts.